# Which sentence is correct? Help laughing or help but laugh

Tags: gerunds

I was wondering which of the following sentence is grammatically correct (British English preferably):

I could not help laughing.
I could not help but laugh.

There is a similar question on this site but that does not explain the grammatical correctness of the above mentioned sentences. References are welcome.

Comment: You know, I was just wondering why German "auslachen" had no English cognate, and what it originally meant. It's literally *to laugh out somebody*, perhaps like *knock-out*, if it meant to ridicule and laugh somebody into the ground, or *away*, if you will; perhaps compare simply *laugh out loud*, rather G *auflachen* (lit. *laugh up*; cp *cry out, speak up*). Now this question comes along and I figure *can't help but laugh* can be rebracketed to be *can't help ut laugh* or the like. It would be mighty odd if that could help solve your question. \*ut "out" is the Proto-Germanic reconstruction

Answer (score 2):

From [Oxford Learner’s Dictionary:](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/help_1)

> somebody cannot help (doing) something,
>
> somebody cannot help but do something,

are

> used to say that it is impossible to prevent or avoid something.

Examples:

> - *I can't help thinking he knows more than he has told us.
>   He can’t help being ugly.
>   She couldn't help but wonder what he was thinking.*